# Codeigniter datatable helper issue

Tags: codeigniter, datatable

I am facing an issue my parameter is not passing as an id it's considering as a string and giving me an error.
myhelper_helper.php

```
function get_branch($branch)
{
  $CI = &get_instance();
  $query = $CI->db->query(“select * from branches where branch_id = $branch”)->row();
  $return = $query->branch_name;
  return $return;
}

public function get_users_datatable()
{
  $this->datatables->select(‘admin.admin_id,name,email,sex,birthday,religion,designation,address,phone,group_name,admin.branch_id,admin.user_id’)
  ->unset_column(‘admin.branch_id’)
  ->add_column(‘Branch’,get_branch(‘$1′),’admin.branch_id’)
  ->from(‘admin’)
  ->join(‘groups’,'groups.group_id=admin.group_id’,'left’)
  ->where(array(‘admin.group_id !=’=>0));

  echo $this->datatables->generate();
  //echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

The error is

```
Error Number: 1054Unknown column ‘$1′ in ‘where clause’select * from admin where admin_id
= $1Filename: D:\xamp\htdocs\dnspak\vivid\system\database\DB_driver.phpLine Number: 331
```

Comment: i suggest you one thing if you are running `SELECT` query then kindly write your query directly without using in_built functions so that you can append any` where` condition in future based on your  other situations...right now i am not getting your query completely...so kindly write query without using functions

Answer (score 0):

In your helper for are doing create instance and run sql query but you are not fetching values from database using codeigniter.

```
function get_branch($branch)
{
$CI = &get_instance();
$query = $CI->db->query(“select * from branches where branch_id = $branch”);
$result = $query->row();
$return = $result->branch_name;
return $return;

}
```

If you will do like above code then you will get record.